# What is the best practices fetch and insert multiple data?

Tags: java, database, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I want to fetch 500,000 records from the database and extract the data from these records and save them in another table.

I am using java 11 and spring boot.

What is the best practice of this ?

Should I use JDBCTemplate ?

Should I use more than one thread?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Work it out on a subset first. Pure DB part, code based gathering and processing. Careful on transactions and locking tables. Measuring times (profiling). Maybe temporary indices. Multithreading: In general it does not make sense to split 1000 records in 2 threads of 500 records. But do run-wait phases of a process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose is to extract data from one query and insert them into another table, I'd wonder why you would want to bring them to the middle tier at all.  Why not have the database server do all the work?  You won't incur the cost of transferring half a million records back and forth across the network or the memory and CPU on the middle tier.

Write a query or stored procedure to create the data in the database.

JDK 17 is the current version you should be using.

`JDBCTemplate` is a wonderful class.  You should be able to write the SQL and execute it on the database server if you can write it for the class.

You shouldn't consider threads until you've managed to execute it once with a single thread and measured performance.

You should be thinking more about units of work, transactions, ACID, and isolation.

Comment: I made a sql and execute it. 
String sql = "INSERT INTO A_TABLE (other_id)"
+"SELECT "
+"id "
+"FROM " 
+"B_TABLE "
jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
Thanks